# Java - Reading from an ArrayList from another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

We've not covered ArrayLists only Arrays and 2D arrays. What I need to do is be able to read from an ArrayList from another class. The main aim is to read from them in a for loop and use the values stored in them to display items. However, I have made this quick program to test it out and keep getting this error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at Main.Main(Main.java:14)
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
        ArrayList <Objects> xcoords = new ArrayList<Objects>();

        for( int x = 1 ; x < xcoords.size() ; x++ )
        {
            System.out.println(xcoords.get(x));
        }
    }
}
```

And then the class where the ArrayList is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Objects
{
    public void xco()
    {
        ArrayList xcoords = new ArrayList();
        //X coords
        //Destroyable
        xcoords.add(5);
        xcoords.add(25);
        xcoords.add(5);
        xcoords.add(5);
        xcoords.add(25);
        xcoords.add(5);
        //Static Walls
        xcoords.add(600);
        xcoords.add(400);
        xcoords.add(600);
    }
}
```

If someone can point me in the correct direction it would be so valuable. I've tried to debug however I can get anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This wouldn't work with an array either. I don't think you grasp how objects or methods work, or what variable scoping is. Aside from that, the code above *isn't* throwing that exception as `size()` would return `0`

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about doing this? Keeping in mind I'm just learning everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the exception is due to indexing location 1 of an `ArrayList` with 0 elements. Notice where you start you for loop index variable `x`. But consider this line:

```
ArrayList <Objects> xcoords = new ArrayList<Objects>();
```

`xcoords` points to a new, empty `ArrayList`, not the one you created in class Objects. To get *that* `ArrayList`, change the method `xco` like

```
public ArrayList<Integer> xco() { // make sure to parameterize the ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> xcoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // .. add all the elements ..

    return xcoords;
}
```

then, in your `main` method

```
public static void main(String [] args) { // add correct arguments

    //..
    ArrayList <Integer> xcoords = (new Objects()).xco();

    for( int x = 0 ; x < xcoords.size() ; x++ ) { // start from index 0
        System.out.println(xcoords.get(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes so much sense when you've said it like that. I'm going to try this with a few other things to make sure I fully grasp it but thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Here you're simply creating two completely unrelated lists. Either have the array list be a property of the `Objects` class and retrieve it through an instance method, or return it from an instance or static method, or make the property static. IMO the first two are preferable in most situations.

```
public class Objects {
    public static List<Integer> getXcoords() {
        List<Integer> xcoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Your same code, but adding:
        return xoords;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    // Note the lower-case "main" here. You want that.
    public static void main() {
        List<Integer> xcoords = Objects.getXcoords();
        // etc.
```

Also, your `List` should be of `Integer`, not of `Objects`, which would create a collection holding instances of `Objects`. You may want to take a step back and relate lists to arrays in a better way--you wouldn't create an array of `Objects`, would you? No, you'd have an array of `int` or `Integer`.

Also, there's `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Thank you so much, both you and paislee where very helpful, however he explained it in a way I understood a bit easier. Altho your last statment about Array of Object was very good. Thank you ever so much again! Also, if I could '+' your post I would, however I can due to rep :/ When I can I will, thanks so much again

Answer (score 1):

You have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which means that you are trying to access an element in an array which is not existing.

But in your code posted here you are not accessing an array at all (your for loop will not execute once because the list is empty), which means that your exception is thrown somewhere else.

But also your code doesn't make any sense. I refactored it for you while staying as close to your code as possible, so you can see how it could work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Objects myObjects = new Objects();
    ArrayList<Integer> listFromMyObjects = myObjects.getList();
    for( int x = 0 ; x < listFromMyObjects.size() ; x++ )
    {
        System.out.println(listFromMyObjects.get(x));
    }
}


public class Objects
{   
    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;

    public Objects(){
        myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(25);
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(25);
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(600);
        myList.add(400);
        myList.add(600);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList(){
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Again with the other answers I have no a much better understanding and can see the reason I went wrong. Makes a lot of sense now It's been explain like that thanks!